# Multi-threaded VPN application - multiple tun/tap interfaces, or?

Tags: linux, multithreading, networking

I'm developing a Linux based VPN application.  The application will be establishing customized TLS based connections to multiple destinations.  Client machines will be routing traffic to the Linux box running this VPN application.

I intend to use the tun/tap device to grab the traffic.  As we will have some substantial load, the intent is to use a multi-threaded approach, where multiple worker threads will be handling the VPN connections to the different locations.

My question is regarding the tun interface side of things.  Would it be more efficient (or even possible), to have each worker thread allocate a tun interface, then use the Kernel route table to route the appropriate traffic to each tun interface?

OR... just use a master worker thread, which will pull packets off a single tun interface, and then distribute those packets to each worker thread to be sent off to the appropriate VPN?

I would think the second approach would lead to a bottleneck, but is simpler to use than multiple interfaces regarding setup.

The first approach, however, avoids passing the messages between master thread to worker thread, and routing back to the source tun interface is automatic.

Suggestions?